# Bernoulli and Euler numbers in some known series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, taylor-expansion

The series for some day to day functions such as $\tan z$ and $\cot z$ involve them. So does the series for $\dfrac{z}{e^z-1}$ and the Euler Maclaurin summation formula. How can it be analitically shown that their generating functions are:

$$\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty B_n \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

$$\operatorname{sech} z =\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty E_n \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

as an introductory example?

I've read a little about $A_n$ numbers and their relation to the tangent and secant, which might lead to a new question, but I guess I'm OK with a proof of the first two series.

Comment: What in the world are "$A_n$ numbers"?!? Anyway, why not just look up Bernoulli and Euler numbers on Wikipedia?

Comment: @KCd $A_n$ numbers are the alternating permutation numbers, as called in Wikipedia. There is no proof there, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: What definitions are you using for $B_n$ and $E_n$? I ask because the series you give are often used as the definitions and therefore are (by definition!) correct.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh! I see. What I mean is, how do you show that they generate the given funciton?

Comment: If you **define** $B_n$ to be the coefficients in the Taylor series for $z/(e^z-1)$, then showing they generate that function is just a matter a pointing to the definition. And many sources define $B_n$ exactly that way. That's why I asked you, how are **you** defining these numbers?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. $P_m(n)$ as a polynomial in $n$ doesn't have a nonzero constant term, does it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Possibly he means that he defines the Bernoulli numbers in terms of the coefficients in the polynomials $P_p(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^p$; as in "Faulhaber's formula": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula But yeah, it's not clear what definition is being used.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I didn't express that correctly. Bernoulli defined the numbers as the independent constant in the [Bernoulli polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials), right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Bernoulli numbers, take a look at Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*, Sections 6.5 and 7.6. In 6.5 they define the Bernoulli numbers $B_k$ by the implicit recurrence $$\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{m+1}jB_j=[m=0]\tag{1}$$ for all $m\ge 0$. (The righthand side is an Iverson bracket.) They then prove the identity $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^m=\frac1{m+1}\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m+1}kB_kn^{m+1-k}\;.$$

In 7.6, on exponential generating functions, they rewrite $(1)$ by substituting $n$ for $m+1$ and adding $B_n$ to both sides to get $$\sum_k\binom{n}kB_k=B_n+[n=1]\tag{2}$$ for all $n\ge 0$. The lefthand side of $(2)$ is the binomial convolution of $\langle B_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ and the constant $1$ sequence. The egf of the constant $1$ sequence is just $e^z$; let $$\widehat B(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0}B_n\frac{z^n}{n!}\;,$$ the egf of $\langle B_n:n\in\omega\rangle$. Then $$\sum_k\binom{n}kB_k=\widehat B(z)e^z\;.$$ On the other hand, the egf of the righthand side of $(2)$ is $$\sum_{n\ge 0}\Big(B_n+[n=1]\Big)\frac{z^n}{n!}=\widehat B(z)+z\;,$$ so $$\widehat B(z)e^z=\widehat B(z)+z\;,$$ and $$\widehat B(z)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}\;.$$ The relationship with the Bernoulli polynomials is explored further in the next few pages.

I can’t help with the Euler (secant) numbers: I’ve only ever seen them defined as the coefficients in the Maclaurin expansion of $\operatorname{sech} x$. You might look at Exercise 7.41 and its solution, however, since it shows the connection between the up-down numbers and the tangent and secant functions.

**Added:** Suppose that $\widehat A(x)$ and $\widehat B(x)$ are exponential generating functions for $\langle a_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ and $\langle b_n:n\in\omega\rangle$, respectively, so that $$\widehat A(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n\quad\text{ and }\quad\widehat B(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{b_n}{n!}x^n\;.$$

Now let $$c_n=\sum_k\binom{n}ka_kb_{n-k}\;;$$ the sequence $\langle c_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ is the *binomial convolution* of $\langle a_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ and $\langle b_n:n\in\omega\rangle$. Let $\widehat C(x)$ be the egf of this binomial convolution. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\widehat C(x)&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{c_n}{n!}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_k\left(\frac{a_n}{k!}\cdot\frac{b_{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\right)x^n\\
&=\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{b_n}{n!}x^n\right)\\
&=\widehat A(x)\widehat B(x)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Just as ordinary convolution of sequences is reflected in the product of their ordinary generating functions, binomial convolution of sequences is reflected in the product of their exponential generating functions.

Comment: I'm surprised you wrote an answer like this without up-voting the question.

Comment: @Michael: Sheer oversight on my part, now remedied.

Comment: @Brian Great answer. But, shouldn't the second equation be $k^m$ instead of $k_m$? And, could you add a little on the binomial convolution? It's new to me. Also, I can't understand what "egf" and "rhe" is. Thank you!

Comment: @Peter: You’re right: $k_m$ was a typo for $k^m$, and *Rhe* was a typo for *The*, both now fixed. I thought that *egf* would be clear in context: it’s a semi-standard abbreviation for *exponential generating function*.

Comment: @Brian OH! Right. I'm just lost on the binomial convolution of $⟨B_n:n \in \omega⟩$. Should I check what it is on the book?

Comment: @Peter: You could, since it’s right there in Section 7.6, but for reference I’ll add a little addendum to the answer.